# Scraping accessibility JSON

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, accessibility

I need to parse a website that uses JS and dynamically loads from various other sites. The information I'm looking for is not exposed in the source code, and the site also does not seem to have an API for easily accessing the data that is being loaded. However, I can see it perfectly in the Mozilla Accessibility Inspector module (right-click -> "Inspect Accessibility Properties", or "Tools"/"Web Developer"/"Accessibility"). This can be exported to JSON easily (right-click -> show as JSON) and then saved. My question is how to retrieve this data automatically, preferably in Python.

For example, for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page, I am looking for the following file:

[image]

Thank you for any help!

Comment: u need to see web scraping :)

Comment: You will have to use `requests` or `urllib` (or similar) to load HTML from server and later `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml` (or similar) to search elements from HTML - but for differenet elements it will need separated code. Simple tables in HTML you could get with `pandas.read_html(url)` and it returns all tables as `DataFrames` (PL: powodzenia :) )

Comment: what browser do you use ? I don't see `JSON` in `Accessibility` in my `Firefox`

Comment: @furas thanks for the answer! I know that. What I am looking for is not in the HTML. To give you an example, I try accessing the odds for a particular tennis match in https://www.flashscore.com/tennis/ (I don't provide a link to any particular match, because it would expire shortly). The odds won't be found in the source code, neither they are loaded in the background by a script. But they are linked from another websites, and you can find them in the Accessibility JSON. I wonder whether I can retrieve this file automatically. Or, maybe, there is another way to acess it.

Comment: @furas in order to export the JSON from Accessibility tab, open the tab, right-click somewhere in the section, and select "View as JSON".

Comment: OK. it opens it in new tab and it has all data in `url` as `base64`. So this JSON is created by browser and you can't access it as web page. You can only manually copy this `url` with `base64` and use `Python` to convert `base64` to normal data.

Comment: I checked in Google `convert HTML to JSON` and there is Python module for this - and this can be some method to get page as JSON. [Convert HTML source code to JSON Object using Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-html-source-code-to-json-object-using-python/) But if you want to search in JSON then maybe it would be simpler to search in original HTML - you have modules `Beautifulsoup` and `lxml` which can use `xpath`

Comment: The AOM is in browser but doesn't have an API yet. See more here on the developing specification: https://wicg.github.io/aom/explainer.html

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! I see that the file I was able to produce in the browser cannot be easily retrieved. My goal was not so much to access this very file, but to get the data it included. As I mentioned, @furas, that data (live betting odds) were not in the HTML, so BS won't do here. But finally I was able to track this data in the "Network" tab, and then retrieve it using the Requests library. I guess this is how it should be (may be) done in case of dynamically loading pages. It was my mistake that I thought this data doesn't appear there, but appears only in the "Accessiblity" tab.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and finally solved it by getting the value from selenium via javascript

```
name = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('Name').value")
```